# Why doesn't this document.innerHTML function work?

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

I am not sure why if you trigger the function, nothing happens

```
loginButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  if (password === "password") {
    alert("Correct!");
    document.innerHTML = <embed src="http://stackoverflow.com" style="width:500px; height: 700px;"></embed>;
  } else {
    loginMessage.textContent = "Invalid password.";
  }
});
```

I was expecting a embed of a website

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are at least four separate reasons your code doesn't work.

## `document` doesn't support `innerHTML`

[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is a property found on HTML elements. The [`document` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) is not an HTML element.

Consider `document.body.innerHTML` instead.

## `innerHTML` expects a string

As pointed out by [Mina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14898065/mina), `<embed src="http://stackoverflow.com" style="width:500px; height: 700px;"></embed>` is a syntax error in JavaScript.

You should see this error reported in the Console of your browser's [developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Developer_Tools).

You need to assign a [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#creating_strings) to `innerHTML`. Wrap the code in `'` (or `"` and escape the `"` in the data).

`= '<embed src="http://stackoverflow.com" style="width:500px; height: 700px;"></embed>';`

## `<embed>` isn't for HTML documents

Also note that [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed):

> Keep in mind that most modern browsers have deprecated and removed support for browser plug-ins, so relying upon `<embed>` is generally not wise if you want your site to be operable on the average user's browser.

Consider `<iframe>` instead.

## Stackoverflow forbids it

Stackoverflow has a [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) that forbids other sites from embedding it.

Answer (score 2):

you want to add an embed element to the body element of the document, so we need to access the body element explicitly.
Also, the HTML content should be enclosed in quotes.
It should be modified to:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = '<embed src="http://stackoverflow.com" style="width:500px; height: 700px;"></embed>';
```